# Excel open workbook not found

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have two Excel files with Macros in them.

One is already open, the second one is opened out of powershell and a Macro is run.

Now in the Macro I want to switch back to the first file:

```
Windows("file1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
```

Doesn't work -> runtime error (file / window not found).

If I open the second file by hand, everything works.

So it looks like if the second file is opened through powershell it doesn't "see" the already open workbooks.

Any idea how to fix this anybody?

Comment: Are both of them in the same Excel session? Doesn't PowerShell create a new session and open the second one in it? Try looking in TaskManager processes and see how many Excel.exe processed you can see. If more then one, I can show you a way to identify the necessary one. If only one, this only means that no other workbook has been created in any other application...

Comment: @ASD True, PowerShell did not open that other file, Excel did on its own. Both Excel instances run in a separate runspace, so you cannot simply switch to another sheet between the files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Exactly guys, that's what i thought. It opens the second file in another process. So Fane, what's your plan?

Comment: OK. I suppose that you know the created workbook full name. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Please, try the updated code. Now, it finds the session where the necessary workbook is open, close it, quit that Excel session and open it in the same session as the workbook running the code. As active workbook, but already set as `wb`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved this:

Instead of starting a new session for Excel:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

I just open the new file in the same session:

```
$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
```